# Access/Excel VBA: Getting the two dates corresponding to last week

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I think I can do this with a loop but since I am using this in conjunction with MS Access I wondered if there was a quick way to do this.

Right now it is April 3rd, 2014. I want to be able to return the dates corresponding to the Sunday and Saturday that bookend the previous week.

So for example that would be March 23rd (Sunday) through March 29th (Saturday) last week.

Comment: Use the weekday function and a bit of subtraction.

Comment: I did that with a loop but fear it is suboptimal / too slow to use repeatedly.

Comment: If it becomes an issue then address it then. Premature optimisation is the root of all evil!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel formulae:

```
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())-6  'Sunday of last week
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())    'Saturday of last week
=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())+6  'Friday of current week
```

In VBA:

```
Date()-Weekday(Date())-6     'Sunday of last week
Date()-Weekday(Date())       'Saturday of last week
Date()-Weekday(Date())+6     'Friday of current week
```

Comment: Will this work no matter which day M-F I run it on? I believe it does but want to verify

Comment: Is there a way to get the Friday of the current week?

Comment: 1. Yes, this will work for any day of the week.  2. See edit to answer.

Comment: I had done today()-weekday(today(),3)+4 -- is this the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Previous Sunday:

```
=A1-WEEKDAY(A1)-6
```

Saturday

```
=A1-WEEKDAY(A1)
```

Comment: This returns the previous Sun / Sat dates based on a date in cell A1.  If you want it based on today, then mwolfe02's answer is correct.